# HttpListener: The requested address is not valid in this context

Tags: c#, http, mono

When creating an `HttpListener` object using

```
var server = new HttpListener();
server.Prefixes.Add("http://*:8080/");
server.Start();
```

everything works fine. However, when I use

```
var server = new HttpListener();
server.Prefixes.Add("http://demindiro.com:8080/");
server.Start();
```

it throws `System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (0x80004005): The requested address is not valid in this context` (full stacktrace below).

After googling the exception, it was rather clear it had something to do with the address used. After digging in the **Mono** source code for [HttpListener](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/System/System.Net/HttpListener.cs) and [EndPointManager](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/System/System.Net/EndPointManager.cs) I determined the issue probably lies within this section of code (at [GetEPListener](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/7e7d8a3b4fccfaca91ef74b963f495c704e07085/mcs/class/System/System.Net/EndPointManager.cs#L80-L97)):

```
static EndPointListener GetEPListener (string host, int port, HttpListener listener, bool secure)
{
    IPAddress addr;
    if (host == "*")
        addr = IPAddress.Any;
    else if (IPAddress.TryParse(host, out addr) == false){
        try {
#pragma warning disable 618
            IPHostEntry iphost = Dns.GetHostByName(host);
#pragma warning restore 618
            if (iphost != null)
                addr = iphost.AddressList[0]; // <---
            else
                addr = IPAddress.Any;
        } catch {
            addr = IPAddress.Any;
        }
        // ...    
    }
```

It occurs to me that in almost all cases `ÌPAddress.Any` is used except when it can associate an external IP address with the given host name.

However, I can only assume this was intentional because it is rather explicitly written and it seems `HttpListener` works just fine for other developers, so at this point, I'm clueless as to what is going wrong here.

---

Stacktrace:

```
Unhandled Exception:
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (0x80004005): The requested address is not valid in this context
  at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Bind (System.Net.EndPoint localEP) [0x00043] in <50d80b08c1a5449282b22aedf03ce925>:0 
  at System.Net.EndPointListener..ctor (System.Net.HttpListener listener, System.Net.IPAddress addr, System.Int32 port, System.Boolean secure) [0x00047] in <50d80b08c1a5449282b22aedf03ce925>:0 
  at System.Net.EndPointManager.GetEPListener (System.String host, System.Int32 port, System.Net.HttpListener listener, System.Boolean secure) [0x0009d] in <50d80b08c1a5449282b22aedf03ce925>:0 
  at System.Net.EndPointManager.AddPrefixInternal (System.String p, System.Net.HttpListener listener) [0x0005e] in <50d80b08c1a5449282b22aedf03ce925>:0 
  at System.Net.EndPointManager.AddListener (System.Net.HttpListener listener) [0x0009c] in <50d80b08c1a5449282b22aedf03ce925>:0 
  at System.Net.HttpListener.Start () [0x0000f] in <50d80b08c1a5449282b22aedf03ce925>:0 
  at Playground.Playground.StartHttpListener () [0x00016] in <d51cc6c047ee47c9a05c5e174876cbec>:0 
  at Playground.Playground.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in <d51cc6c047ee47c9a05c5e174876cbec>:0 
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (0x80004005): The requested address is not valid in this context
  at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Bind (System.Net.EndPoint localEP) [0x00043] in <50d80b08c1a5449282b22aedf03ce925>:0 
  at System.Net.EndPointListener..ctor (System.Net.HttpListener listener, System.Net.IPAddress addr, System.Int32 port, System.Boolean secure) [0x00047] in <50d80b08c1a5449282b22aedf03ce925>:0 
  at System.Net.EndPointManager.GetEPListener (System.String host, System.Int32 port, System.Net.HttpListener listener, System.Boolean secure) [0x0009d] in <50d80b08c1a5449282b22aedf03ce925>:0 
  at System.Net.EndPointManager.AddPrefixInternal (System.String p, System.Net.HttpListener listener) [0x0005e] in <50d80b08c1a5449282b22aedf03ce925>:0 
  at System.Net.EndPointManager.AddListener (System.Net.HttpListener listener) [0x0009c] in <50d80b08c1a5449282b22aedf03ce925>:0 
  at System.Net.HttpListener.Start () [0x0000f] in <50d80b08c1a5449282b22aedf03ce925>:0 
  at Playground.Playground.StartHttpListener () [0x00016] in <d51cc6c047ee47c9a05c5e174876cbec>:0 
  at Playground.Playground.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in <d51cc6c047ee47c9a05c5e174876cbec>:0
```

---

PS: I explicitly want to use `demindiro.com`, not `*`.

PS2: I know there are many topics concerning this particular exception, but none seem to concern `HttpListener.Start()` throwing this exception.

---

**UPDATE**
I've googled my issue again but this time I looked specifically for `TcpListener` and I found this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17092670/7327379

> The TcpListener can only be bound to a local IP Address of the computer that runs it. So the IP you're specifying isn't an IP of the local machine. Your public IP isn't the same IP as your local machine, especially if you're using some kind of NAT.
>
> If I recall correctly, it's common to just do IPAddress.Any as your IP to initialise the listener.

So if I get this straight, this means that to bind to my external IP, I somehow have to go from this

```
Server <-- local IP --> Modem <-- external IP --> The Internet
```

to this

```
Server <-- external IP --> The Internet
```

Is this correct? If yes, how do you connect a server to the internet without a modem? Or what else should I do?

Comment: *This* is how you ask a question!

Comment: Not sure if it's the problem, but looking [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httplistenerprefixcollection.add(v=vs.110).aspx) I'm seeing a lot of "The prefix must be terminated with a forward slash ("/")", "Make sure the string is terminated with a "/"", etc. Couldn't help but notice that yours doesn't end with a slash.

Comment: @itsme86 My bad! The actual code does have a prefix with a terminating "/". I will update my question. (Also thanks for the compliment :) )

Comment: Does `demindiro.com` resolve to an address that is allocated to one of your NICs?

Comment: @spender If you mean if `demindiro.com` points to my external IP, then yes (the server is a RPi3 connected to a modem).

Comment: If you manually run Dns.GetHostByName("demindiro.com") from your machine, does it return an address that's actually bound to your NIC? I'm checking to make sure there isn't some load balancer, or other network device that's sitting in front of your server.

Comment: @DevOhrion Running `Dns.GetHostByName` gives me only one IPv4 address (`109.132.169.132` at the time of writing) that is my external IP.

Comment: Now that I think about it: does it matter that I don't have a static IP? Binding to a specific IP seems a bit "silly" when it may change in the future anyways.

Comment: By "my external ip" what do you mean exactly? Is it listed at "ip addr list" command output (I assume you are on Linux since using mono)?

Comment: Please explain why you want to use `demindiro.com` and not `*`?

Comment: @Evk with "my external IP" I mean the public IP of the modem my server is connected to.

Comment: @TarunLalwani I want to use `demindiro.com` specifically because [MSDN recommends it](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httplistener(v=vs.110).aspx) for security reasons (admittedly, I don't know exactly how exactly it may be dangerous, but I prefer being as safe as possible). I also want to use it because it makes it easier to have multiple domain names pointing to the same IP and have other methods be executed based on the domain used.

Comment: @Demindiro, the documentation you are referring to is for .NET framework and not Mono. Mono implementation are similar to .NET but not always same. And I think that may be the difference here. The behaviour based on the source code you shared aligns with what I explained earlier in my answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can visualise your network something like below

```
local machine -> local interface 
              -> interface 1 (Private IP) <-> External IP
              -> interface 2 (Private IP2) <-> External IP
```

Now in most cases your VM in the cloud will have 1 network interface and one local interface. Local interfaces is the loopback interface and the `interface 1` will have a `Private IP`.

Now when you use below in your code

```
server.Prefixes.Add("http://*:8080/");
```

It means bind to all interfaces on your machine. Which means if you do

```
curl http://localhost:8080
```

or

```
curl http://<privateIP>:8080
```

Both would work.

Now if you map `example.com` to the `externalIP` run below command it will work as well

```
curl http://example.com:8080
```

This is because your `example.com` maps to `<extrenalIP>`, which will forward all traffic to the `<privateIP>`. Now when you use below in your . code

```
server.Prefixes.Add("http://example.com:8080/");
```

It translate to

```
server.Prefixes.Add("http://<externalIP>:8080/");
```

And this not a valid IP in the context, only the `127.0.0.1` and the `<PrivateIP>` of the machine are valid. So if you have multiple interfaces then only you should worry about not using `*`. Now if you have multiple interfaces and your a specific interface to listen for your domain then you will make a entry of the same in your `/etc/hosts` file like below

```
<PrivateIP> example.com
```

And then you can use

```
server.Prefixes.Add("http://example.com:8080/");
```

Now if your concern is that someone can point to your machine with a different host name and you don't want to server to respond in such a case. Then you will have to check for the `Host` header in your code and reject the request based on the same. Or you can use a webserver like `nginx` and only respond to request directed towards `example.com`

Answer (score 5):

Considering that http://demindiro.com appears to work, this might be redundant.  However...

There are a few things here that you need to be aware of:

### Binding via host name is bad

In general binding by host name is A Bad Idea™.  If the host name resolves to multiple addresses - `localhost` when you have IPv6 enabled for instance, or when you have multiple IPv4 addresses on the same machine, etc - you don't get to control which of those addresses it binds to.  In the case of `localhost` you can be (sometimes unpleasantly) surprised to find that it binds to `::1` but not `127.0.0.1`.

The problem here however is that `demindiro.com` is a name that doesn't resolve to an internal IP address that is present on the computer, so you can't bind to it directly.  To be precise, `demindiro.com` is a host name that resolves (via DNS) to the IPv4 address `109.132.169.132` which is (almost certainly) not an IP address that your computer has.

### Binding to a host name doesn't bind to a host name

Instead it binds to the first IP address that the host name resolves to on the machine.  No more, no less.

Let's say you modify your host file to have `demindiro.com` resolve (on your machine only) to a valid local IPv4 address, like `192.168.0.123`.  If I am on your network and I make a connection to that address, I get your service.  Doesn't matter what host name I am trying to get to, as long as it resolves to that address I'm going to get a connection.  I could connect directly via IP, or any host name that resolves to that IP, and you will never know.

It's only after a connection has been made and the request has been parsed that you can (sometimes) detect which host name was the target of the request.

In the case of HTTP(S) requests the host name is generally sent as a part of the request.  This allows web servers to host more than a single site on the same address.  The web server receives the request, figures out where it should be routed among the local sites, then sends the request on to the resolved site.  It has been a bit more difficult to do in HTTPS, but that problem is mostly solved by [SNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication).

But if I make an HTTP 1.0 request to your service using an absolute path with no hostname... then what?

### Bindings can only be local

In other words, you can't bind to an address that isn't present on the machine running your code.  More to the point, you can't directly bind to the public address of your internet connection unless it terminates directly on your machine.  Since not many of us are running dial-up or bridging PPPoE to our desktops, the address you're trying to bind to is probably not available.

In general what you need to do is set up some sort of NAT redirect on your internet connection to translate incoming requests on port 8080 to the public address `109.132.169.132` and redirect them to your internal address (`192.168.0.123` or whatever).

That's assuming that `demindiro.com` resolves to your public IP address.  If not then you've got all sorts of other issues.  NAT across a public network is... weird.  Every NAT you add in the chain adds more complexity, more points of failure, etc.