# HttpListener: listen to a port with explicit host name (no top level wildcards)

Tags: c#, httplistener

Suppose I have a machine with an IP for instance `183.41.22.22`. I want to listen to all HTTP messages that will be sent to port 43 of this IP on local host. In fact, I am not really interested in all messages sent to this port, only in messages that are sent to `https://183.41.22.22:443/CustomerData/`

The documentation of [class HttpListener](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httplistener?view=netframework-4.7.2) says that I should add a Prefix. They give an example: `http://www.contoso.com:8080/customerData/`.

Does that mean that in my case I should add prefix `https://183.41.22.22:443/CustomerData/`? Or should I use `https://localhost:443/CustomerData/`?

Alternatively, since my computer is dedicated for this task, I am certain that no one else on my computer should ever receive any messages being sent to port 443. Therefore, according to the same documentation, I could also use a wildcard: `http://*:443`

However, the documentation warns:

> Top-level wildcard bindings (http://*:80/ and http://+:80) should not be used. Top-level wildcard bindings create app security vulnerabilities. This applies to both strong and weak wildcards. Use explicit host names or IP addresses rather than wildcards.

What is an **explicit host name**? Is it the part `CustomerData`?

For those interested, a simplified part of the code (without proper possibility to end the program)

```
using (var httpListener = new HttpListener())
{
    httpListener.Prefixes.Add("https://*:443/");
    httpListener.Start();

    while (true)
    {
        var context = httpListener.GetContext();
        var httpRequest = context.Request();

        // fill the response
        string responseText = this.CreateResponseText(httpRequest);
        byte[] buf = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(responseText);
        context.Response.ContentLength64 = buf.Length;
        context.Response.OutputStream.Write(buf, 0, buf.Length);
    };
```

Comment: You can from cmd.exe do a ping to see what localhost is set to >Ping localhost

Comment: "should I use https://localhost:443/CustomerData/" Have you tried that and what happened?

Comment: Although the prefix `https://*8080` (and other ports) work, I can't test the vulnerabilities that is warned for. So I'm not sure if it is safe to use this prefix

Answer (score 5):

> What is an **explicit host name**? Is it the part CustomerData?

The hostname is what is commonly referred to as 'domain'. See [The components of a URL](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSGMCP_5.1.0/com.ibm.cics.ts.internet.doc/topics/dfhtl_uricomp.html). Also the warning contains more information (which you left out, probably for brevity, but it contains important information):

> Subdomain wildcard binding (for example, `*.mysub.com`) doesn't have this security risk if you control the entire parent domain (as opposed to `*.com`, which is vulnerable). See [rfc7230 section-5.4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-5.4) for more information.

The RFC section refers to the [HTTP Host header](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Client_request). This is part of the HTTP/1.1 spec and was introduced when people started [running more than 1 website on a host](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_hosting) way back in the early days of the web. A host (a "machine") used to simply listen at (commonly) port 80 and serve pages that were requested by clients. But when the web started becoming more widely used a need arised to 'host' several websites on a single machine. You could have `foo.com` and `bar.com`, using DNS, both point to the same IP but then the machine wouldn't know whether to send the `foo.com` homepage or `bar.com`'s homepage. So the Host header was introduced; webbrowsers (more correctly: http clients) could then let the server know which host they were interested in and the correct page could be served.

Note that every part of the domain (e.g. `sub.domain.foo.co.uk`) *potentially* refers to a different host (but they may also, just as well, all point to the same host). Using [top-level domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top-level_domain) wildcards (e.g. `*.com`, or even worse: `*`) is a potential risk because *anyone* can get a `.com` domain (`myevildomain.com`) and point it to your server. If you use `*.company.com` nobody but `company.com` can control the subdomains. *Why* this is a security risk is a whole other story but the gist of it is that using the wildcard `*.com` will make your application respond to any `host` header ending in `.com` whereas `*.company.com` will prevent your application responding to a (likely tricked) client requesting `myevildomain.com`.

Comment: After looking at the rfc, it looks a lot like the * problems are all about applications that could forward the traffic to unitended internal targets or worse they cache data x domain (so they can be flooded with multiple fake domains requests). At least that's the only I got out of it. Do you know of other risks? (intiution says there should be given the phrasing from microsoft's docs, but does not seem to be listed explicitely in the rfc)

Comment: Just wanted to add, one annoying thing is the issue described here https://stackoverflow.com/a/50342157/66372. In fact, it is the reason I ended up reading this answer. Given the stuff in the link, it is almost like in some scenarios (multiple network interfaces) one has no option but to allow the wildcard and maybe check the domain as the first thing when handling the request.

Comment: it seems the security issue microsoft was referring to is called dns rebinding: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNS_rebinding. "This attack can be used to breach a private network by causing the victim's web browser to access computers at private IP addresses and return the results to the attacker". The attacker points the evil dns to their external server first and gets an user to load a page with the evil script and then inmediately changes dns to point to the private IP so the already loaded script in the same evil domain can now send a request to the private IP.