# HttpListener is handling only requests for localhost

Tags: c#, .net, httplistener

I'm testing HttpListener based on the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httplistener.begingetcontext?view=netcore-3.1). My code is very simple. It's a console application running under the admin privilege:

```
[STAThread]
static void Main( string[] args )
{
    var prefixes = new[] { "http://localhost:8080/", "http://www.contoso.com:8080/index/" };
    HttpListener listener = new HttpListener();
    foreach( string s in prefixes )
    {
        listener.Prefixes.Add( s );
    }
    listener.Start();
    IAsyncResult result = listener.BeginGetContext( new AsyncCallback( ListenerCallback ), listener );
    Console.WriteLine( "Waiting for request to be processed asyncronously." );
    result.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne();
    Console.WriteLine( "Request processed asyncronously." );
    Console.ReadLine();
    listener.Close();
}

public static void ListenerCallback( IAsyncResult result )
{
    HttpListener listener = (HttpListener)result.AsyncState;
    HttpListenerContext context = listener.EndGetContext( result );
    HttpListenerRequest request = context.Request;
    HttpListenerResponse response = context.Response;
    string responseString = "<HTML><BODY> Hello world!</BODY></HTML>";
    byte[] buffer = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes( responseString );
    response.ContentLength64 = buffer.Length;
    System.IO.Stream output = response.OutputStream;
    output.Write( buffer, 0, buffer.Length );
    output.Close();
 }
```

If I try `http://localhost:8080/` in a web browser then the callback `ListenerCallback` is called and the response string "Hello world!" appears in the browser.

For `http://www.contoso.com:8080/index/` the callback is never called and the web request timed out.
How can I identify where is the problem? It's a bug in .NET framework or in my code?

Comment: So it's working as expected. What exactly is your question/ problem?

Comment: @MindSwipe I need a help to identify if my code is wrong or if the problem can be in .NET itself.

Comment: The problem is in your understanding, not the code. If you put `http://www.contoso.com:8080/index` into your browser, it makes a DNS request, sees that `www.contoso.com` has an IP address associated with it (`40.76.4.15` for me) and makes a `GET` request to that IP, not your local machine

Comment: @MindSwipe Ok, it's not clear for me from the documentation how HttpListener works and I can't use it to handle all outcoming requests. Thanks.

Comment: @user2250152 did you ever figure it out? at least on linux I definitely see it binding to 127.0.1.1, so localhost only (regardless of the dns being correct)

Answer (score 1):

One reason is if the ip of `www.contoso.com` is not a local IP to the computer where you are running the HttpListener on. Usually because the traffic gets somewhere in your network first and is redirected to the computer that runs the HttpListener which is using a private IP address. Check the [answers here for more](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49267224/66372). Don't blindly take wildcard solutions though, as those can have [security vulnerabilities](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55737356/66372) depending on your scenario.